# How to make alise of relation in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My code is:

```
     $this->model
        ->whereId($id)
        ->with('userRegion.region')
        ->first();
```

The response is

```
    "id": xx,
    "first_name": "sahil",
    "last_name": "gupta",
    "email": "xxxx@yopmail.com",
    "role_id": 0,
    "user_region":[]
```

But I want to rename or create alias of `user_region` as `regions` and then it should look like:

```
        "id": xx,
        "first_name": "sahil",
        "last_name": "gupta",
        "email": "xxxx@yopmail.com",
        "role_id": 0,
        "regions":[]
```

I have tried:

```
      $this->model
        ->whereId($id)
        ->with('userRegion.region as regions')
        ->first();
```

Or

```
       $this->model
            ->whereId($id)
            ->with(['userRegion as regions','userRegion.region'])
            ->first();
```

But they both solution are not working and throwing errors.

Comment: do u want to change the structure to `{"regions": [{..., "region": []}, {...}]}`?

Comment: @TsaiKoga I have just updated my question. Please check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the relationship with name `regions`, just defined the relationship method's name as `regions`:

```php
public function regions() {
    return $this->hasMany(...);
}
```

so you can use `$this->model->whereId($id)->with('regions.region')` .
and the response will be:

```
        "id": xx,
        "first_name": "sahil",
        "last_name": "gupta",
        "email": "xxxx@yopmail.com",
        "role_id": 0,
        "regions":[....]
```

And you can keep the original `userRegion` relationship method, so you can still use `with('userRegions.region')` in other cases. and the regions method call the relationship method:

```php
public function regions() {
    return $this->userRegion();
}
```

Another solution:

Reset the `userRegions` to `regions` by [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)

```php
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'role_id' => $this->role_id,
            'regions' => RegionResource::collection($this->userRegions),
            ...
        ];
    }
```

Comment: We can't create alise?

Comment: Create two different functions for the same relation is the violence of the DRY principle.

Comment: @SahilGupta in the `regions()` method, you can call the relationship method `userRegion`, or you can change the key by [resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#writing-resources)